# Character too large for enclosing character literal type c++

Tags: c++, macos

I have a problem with my code. I see these errors in the following lines of code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        encrypt_string[current_element] = string[i];
        current_element++;
        if (string[i] == 'а' || string[i] == 'е' || 
            string[i] == 'и' || string[i] == 'о' || 
            string[i] == 'у' || string[i] == 'я' || string[i] == 'Я' ||
            string[i] == 'ы' || string[i] == 'ё' || 
            string[i] == 'ю' || string[i] == 'я' || 
            string[i] == 'э' || string[i] == 'a' ||
            string[i] == 'e' || string[i] == 'i' || 
            string[i] == 'o' || string[i] == 'u' || 
            string[i] == 'y') {
            encrypt_string[current_element] = 'л';
            encrypt_string[current_element+1] = 'а';
            current_element += 2;
        }
    }
```

I tried to google on this topic, but the advice on the Internet does not help (Char_16T, Char_32T, ETC.). Perhaps this does not work with MacOS or Clang ++ compiler.

How I can do it on Mac?

Comment: In which encoding are these letters represented? In some encodings they take more than one byte and don't fit into `char`.

Comment: You're getting this warning because the characters you're using cannot be stored in a single-byte `char` type, because they are all actually composed of multiple characters as part of the UTF encoding scheme. Since the size of a `char` is almost always 1 byte, that means the maximum possible integer that any `char` can hold is `255`, and all of the characters you've used are **much** larger than that.